# How to get the option image from order_id

Tags: mysql, opencart

How in Opencart would you get the products + options, say if you know the order_id and I wanted to display an image for each product?

The main reason for this is that I want to display a list of ordered products, each product will have one image either:

1. option_value.image
2. or default product.image

At the moment we get the products by:

```
SELECT *
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (p.product_id = op.product_id)
WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'
```

Comment: You can't really do this in one query as it's going to be massively inefficient to join all of those tables together, then sort them out

Comment: And by what rule You will decide whether to show the Product image or the product's Option image? And what image will be displayed if one product has multiple options (one for color, one for size, etc...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is about:

- ordered product does not have any options, let's display product's image
- or ordered product has exactly one option (and cannot have more), let's display that option's image

then I'd go this way:

1. when retrieving ordered products list, in foreach loop for each ordered product check whether it has set an option (one query per product)
2. if the option is set, go get the option's image (another query)
3. if there is no option, we will use product's image (this should be already loaded within the product)
4. process the image with the one being already set or set as false if there is none
5. display the image in template if it is not false

We could discuss whether

1. loading all of the ordered products and joining their ordered options with option's images
2. or loading just products then query for ordered option and then query for option's image

is better. If I look at the two now I'd say the first should be better as **only one query is executed** but on the other hand it loads much more data where probably a lot of it would be just `NULL`s (all the products where no option is set). I guess it depends on the final endpoint and the communication speed: if all of Your queries tak some time to execute (the connection/communication speed is slow) I'd stick with the first option. But if the connection speeds are in few milliseconds (that means 0-10), then I'd go with the second one as described in the 5 steps above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I see now why it can't be done in one query.